# Redis Sessions in PHP ignoring php.ini settings

Tags: php, session, redis

We recently switched our PHP SESSION management from memcache to Redis.  While the SESSIONs are being stored properly, we noticed that people are now being logged out every 1440s, or the default value for `session.gc_maxlifetime`.  However in our php.ini file, we have the following values set:

```
session.gc_maxlifetime = 86400
session.cookie_lifetime = 86400
```

I've confirmed, via `phpinfo()`, that these values are correctly read ONLY when we have our save handler set as `session.save_handler = files`.  However whenever we have our save handler set to Redis, those php.ini values are ignored and the default PHP values are used.  The Redis lines in our php.ini are:

```
session.save_handler = redis
session.save_path = tcp://127.0.0.1:6379?auth=noauth
```

My thought was that maybe there is another argument I can pass into the session.save_path URL to set the TTL value of the key, but documentation is scarce on which arguments are valid.  Is there a way have Redis get the correct TTL value from php.ini?  Or a way to pass it in the URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to figure out a workaround, however it still doesn't answer why Redis won't read the settings in my php.ini file.  Instead I was able to change the setting in our code and have it properly recognized:

```
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 604800);
session_start();
```